# If someone thanks me for sending him home, can I say "Don't worry, it's along the way"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

If someone thanks me for sending him home, can I say "Don't worry, it's along the way"?

Is along the way used correctly here?

Comment: If you mean _taking_ or giving him a lift home, you can say 'It's on my way'.

Comment: Thank u. Is it wrong to use along the way in this manner?

Comment: _On my way_ is the usual expression, meaning 'on the route I would be taking anyway'.

Answer (score 2):

I'd understand "along the way", but "on the way" is better, or perhaps "on my way".  There is also a common idiom, "It's *en route* to my house/flat" (pronounced as "on route", borrowed from French).

There are lots of ways to say this: "I was coming this way, anyway", "It's not out of my way" and so on.

You aren't "sending someone home" (that is what your boss or your teacher does when he/she says "You must go home now")  You are "taking someone home" (or probably "driving them home" and "giving them a lift".)